# iOS Application framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have created an ios application that can talk to the database and get the messages from the server and all i want to do now is to distribute this aplication as a templet and other application can import my current project and use it, Now i been went throw many tricks and tips such as making an Static framwork using xcode bundles and Aggregate target type and got it work with some script found hear: http://codefriend.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/creating-ios-framework-with-xcode4.html
what i want to know is whether its the correct approach for such a problem or should i been looking at something else. All i want to create is an framework for my team so that they can produce other application 
without worrying about or writing same files and code again and again. And is it possible to bundle all the .xib and .html files too?

Comment: I would use a static library, then put the xib and html files in a bundle. So your team just imports the library and adds the bundle to their project

Comment: So the link above in my question is a static framework? do you know how to make static framework for iOS. Thanks

Comment: its a project option in Xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what we use to create framework:
https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework

Comment: Does apple have any probs with doing this? I also noticed that in Xcode option to built static Framework been removed by apple.

Comment: I also noticed that in Xcode option to built static Framework been removed by apple